# Moment inequality sample moments

Tags: sequences-and-series, descriptive-statistics

> Derive the inequality $b_{2r-2}≥ 1+b_1+b_2+...+b_{2r-3}$ where $b_{2r} =m_{2r+2}/m_{2r+1}$ and $b_{2r+1} =(m_{2r}+3m_3)/m_{2r+3}$

I know that $b_2≥b_1+1$ and determinant of the matrix $((m_{ij}))≥0$, $m_{ij}=$central moment of order $(i+j)$ but can not proceed further.

Comment: this is unreadable. please use mathjax

Comment: here is the MathJax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference